# Disable replace quotes and adding backslash to string on reformat - IntelliJ

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, reformatting

What option inside IntelliJ (WebStorm) controls this update over strings?
I updated the options in "Code Style -> TypeScript -> Punctuation" but on every test they keep happening.

Original not updated string:

[image]

After reformat:

[image]

I'm working on an Angular project and trying to do a reformat of lots of components for bad spacing, indentation, punctuation, etc... but it also modifies/triggers this change, creating thousands of changes so the PR that I'm making in the repo is being rejected.

I disabled Prettier in case it some how it triggered the update but it keeps occurring.

Comment: What is configured in "Code Style -> TypeScript -> Punctuation"? Do you use EditorConfig/prettier in the project?